# SQL Netezza - How to round datetime to nearest hour

Tags: sql, netezza

please i need to get the How to round datetime to nearest hour from a field like below

```
2019-09-29 13:05:42
2019-09-29 13:06:16
2019-09-29 13:04:43
```

Comment: Cast to DATE. Then use `EXTRACT`: 1) extract and add hours 2) extract minutes, if 30 or more, add one hour.

Comment: Alternatively: convert to string of `YYYYMMDDHHMI`, convert to BIGINT, add 20, divide by 100 with rounding to BIGINT, convert back to datetime using `YYYYMMDDHH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()`.  If by "round" you mean truncate, then there is a built-in function:

```
date_trunc('hour', col)
```

If by "round" you really mean "round", then:

```
date_trunc('hour', col + interval '30 minute')
```